# Nonstandard example of using chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x)=\int_0^x g(s,x+s) \,ds$.

Could you please help? I don't know how to start. I suppose I should use the chain rule and the formula $\frac{d}{dx}\,\int_0^x h(s)\,ds=h(x)$ but I don't know in what way.

Comment: Calculate $F\left(x+\Delta x\right)-F\left(x\right)$ manually, then divide by $\Delta x$ and take the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
G(a,b)=\int_0^a g(s,b+s)ds\ .
$$

Now take
$$
G(a(x),b(x))\ .
$$
By the chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx}G(a(x),b(x))=a'(x) \frac{d}{du}G(u,v)\Big|_{u\to a(x),v\to b(x)}+b'(x) \frac{d}{dv}G(u,v)\Big|_{u\to a(x),v\to b(x)}\ .
$$
Now specialize to $a(x)=b(x)=x$. We have:
$$
a'(x)=b'(x)=1
$$
$$
\frac{d}{du}G(u,v)\Big|_{u\to a(x),v\to b(x)}=g(u,b(x)+u)\Big|_{u\to a(x)=x,v\to b(x)=x}=g(x,x+x)=g(x,2x)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dv}G(u,v)\Big|_{u\to a(x),v\to b(x)}=\int_0^{a(x)=x}ds\frac{d}{dv}g(s,v+s)\Big|_{v\to b(x)=x}=\int_0^x ds\frac{d}{dt}g(s,t)\Big|_{t\to x+s}\ .
$$
In summary
$$
\boxed{F'(x)=g(x,2x)+\int_0^x ds\frac{d}{dt}g(s,t)\Big|_{t\to x+s}\ .}
$$

Comment: Thank you fonini and Pierpaolo Vivo for your help :-)